# Importing WAR file in Eclipse. Name's cannot be empty

Tags: eclipse, dynamic, war

I need to create an web app and was following this tutorial at IBM: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509cline/

However, whenever I try to import the LowFareAir.war file in Eclipse I keep getting the message "Name's cannot be empty" and it doesn't let me continue.  I'm a complete beginner to this, am I doing something wrong?  I followed the Eclipse documentation and the documentation on the IBM site for the project and neither works.

Answer (score 4):

Ugh, Eclipse is ridiculous.  It autocompletes the name of the project with the name of the WAR file and gives that error but if I change the name of the project, everything's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Likly, it is the war file you put in the workspace before prevent you from the second time you try to import.  Clear the space first when you try to re-import the war with the same name.  Changing name will import the war file with its second copy to your work space.

Answer (score 1):

Likley, it is the war file you put in the workspace before prevent you from importing the second time.  Clear the space first when you try to re-import the war with the same name.  Changing name will import the war file with its seco
nd copy to your work space.

Answer (score 0):

Before importing the war file check in your workspace whether that project already exists, if so delete it and import the war file again

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same name for the war file and the existing project, This issue may appear. Use a different name for the WAR file (rename). Then, It will be fine.